# How do you backup a SQL Database during release in TFS using command line task?

Tags: tfs, release, sqlcmd

I wish to backup the SQL Database as a step in my TFS release using a Command Line Task as follows:

**Tool**: SqlCmd

**Arguments**: -U *username* -P *password* -S *sqlserver\instance* –Q "BACKUP DATABASE [*mydatabase*] TO DISK='*X:\SomePath\mydatabase.bak*' WITH COPY_ONLY"

The resulting command outputted into the TFS log works if I copy/paste and run it in a command window.

But for some reason, TFS throws an error when it tries to execute the command.

Here's the log info:

> 2018-06-22T02:45:02.1384055Z ##[command]SqlCmd -U *username* -P
>   *password* -S *sqlserver\instance* –Q "BACKUP DATABASE [*mydatabase*] TO DISK='*X:\SomePath\mydatabase.bak*' WITH COPY_ONLY"
>
> 2018-06-22T02:45:02.2009053Z Sqlcmd: '-Q "BACKUP DATABASE [ABS-dev] TO
>   DISK='D:\SQLBACKUP\ABS-dev_Release.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY': Unexpected
>   argument. Enter '-?' for help.   2018-06-22T02:45:02.2634060Z
>
> ### [error]Process completed with exit code 1.

I'm wondering if a clue is that the line indicating the error has not been terminated with double-quotes and have tried things like adding additional double-quotes around the query segement but have had no luck thus far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Is your build agent running on a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

You could try argument below, use `/Q` instead of `-Q`:

```
-U username -P password -S sqlserver\instance /Q "BACKUP DATABASE [mydatabase] TO DISK='X:\SomePath\mydatabase.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY"
```